# Variable does not exist error while trying to set custom field on ContentVersion record

Tags: apex, contentversion

I'm trying to do something relatively mundane, which is store an offset value for Timezone on a custom field on the ContentVersion object. It seems like no matter what field I reference (including standard fields) I'm getting a 'variable does not exist' error.

```
public void setOffset(List<ContentVersion> contentVersions){
    for(ContentVersion cv : contentVersions){
        cv.Timezone_Offset_in_Hours__c=0;
    }
}
```

I know ContentVersion is a little weird in terms of security, but I have no trouble querying these fields through the dev console query editor, and the fields even auto-prompt through the developer console interface. So it seems a bit weird to me.

Is there some quirk I'm unaware of around setting contentversion custom fields via apex?

Comment: From where you are calling this method? Add that part of code as well

Comment: I don't think we have some setting for this. Can you relogin and try again. I tried using the same did not face any issue

Comment: is this a compile time error, or a runtime error?

Comment: I think you have not queried the field. As you are sending the list as a parameter, make sure that you are querying the field when you are creating the list.

Comment: Please provide the full error message text in the question ([edit] to add it).

Answer (score 0):

Update: it was almost as mundane as the use case. There was an apex class of the same name as the SObject in the org. :-|

Comment: chalk another one up for name shadowing